# Pass data from a csv file to a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv

What I would like to do is manage to put each row of the route within a sublist.

The code I've made is this one:

```
l=[]
s=f.readline()
while s!='':
    for x in s:
        if x not in [';',]:
            l.append(x)
    s=f.readline()
print(l)
```

The code should be without imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Skip the first row (`10;10;;...`), it's not needed.
2. Read each line and split on `';'` chars.
3. The `'o'`s appear as the "margins" on the left and right, so filter those out per `row`
4. If the `row` still has something (non-empty) then append it to `lines`.

   - This helps to skip the start and end rows which are just `o`'s

```py
lines = []
with open(csvfile) as f:
    f.readline()  # skip the first line, not needed
    for line in f:
        if line.endswith('\n'):  # in case the last line doesn't end in a newline
            line = line[:-1]
        # create a row which ignores the 'o's
        row = [c for c in line.split(';') if c != 'o']
        if row:  # skip empty rows (all 'o's)
            lines.append(row)

print(lines)
```

Output (list of lists):

```
[['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '', '', ''],
 ['x', '', '', '', '', '', 'x', '', '', ''],
 ['x', 'x', '', '', '', '', 'x', 'x', 'x', ''],
 ['', 'x', 'x', '', '', '', '', '', 'x', 'x'],
 ['', '', 'x', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'x'],
 ['x', 'x', 'x', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'x'],
 ['x', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'x'],
 ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '', '', '', 'x'],
 ['', '', '', '', '', 'x', '', '', '', 'x'],
 ['', '', '', '', '', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
]
```

And if you do *really* want all those `o`'s wherever they appear, then remove some of the `if` conditions:

```py
lines = []
with open(csvfile) as f:
    f.readline()  # skip the first line
    for line in f:
        if line.endswith('\n'):  # in case the last line doesn't end in a newline
            line = line[:-1]
        row = [c for c in line.split(';')]
        lines.append(row)

print(lines)

# output:

[['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
 ['o', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '', '', '', 'o'],
 ['o', 'x', '', '', '', '', '', 'x', '', '', '', 'o'],
 ['o', 'x', 'x', '', '', '', '', 'x', 'x', 'x', '', 'o'],
 ['o', '', 'x', 'x', '', '', '', '', '', 'x', 'x', 'o'],
 ['o', '', '', 'x', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'x', 'o'],
 ['o', 'x', 'x', 'x', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'x', 'o'],
 ['o', 'x', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'x', 'o'],
 ['o', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '', '', '', 'x', 'o'],
 ['o', '', '', '', '', '', 'x', '', '', '', 'x', 'o'],
 ['o', '', '', '', '', '', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'o'],
 ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o']]
```

Comment: Is there any equivalen for endswith?

Comment: [`endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) is a Python builtin for strings. But if you don't want to use it, then do `if line[-1] == '\n'):` since it's only checking the last character of the line.

Comment: Or as one line, you can do `line = line[:-1] if line[-1] == '\n' else line`

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to use `csv` module

```
import csv
with open('blah.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    rows=list(csv_reader)
path=rows[1:]
print(path)
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with the first two values.
But you can easily get them from `rows`

Comment: The first two numbers are the rows and columns of the route without the 'o'. What I would like to do is manage to put each row of the route within a sublist. (If it can be a code without imports)

Comment: Looks like my code solve your problem? Or i still don't get it)

Comment: Yes, sorry. But would there be any way to do it without imports?

Comment: Yes, you can try this: `rows = [row.split(';') for row in open('blah.csv').readlines()]`.

Comment: And to get rid of '\n' you can do something like `for row in rows: row[len(row)-1] = row[len(row)-1].rstrip()`

Comment: but `csv` is a standard module, you don't lose anything by using it